# How to list the available Wifi access point in worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-geolocation

I have to list the available wifi access point in my app by using worklight .  How to do that using worklight.

Answer (score 2):

For some sample code showing how to continually acquire all the access points for a set of SSIDs see: 
[Differentiating between indoor areas](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_differentiating_between_indoor_areas.html?lang=en) in the Knowledge Center.

You can use a wildcard (*) for the SSID and MAC in the access point filters.

If you just want a one-time acquisition use the [WL.Device.Wifi.acquireVisibleAccessPoints](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.Wifi.html%23acquireVisibleAccessPoints) API.

Note that on non-Android platforms, you are limited to information about the connected access point. See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_location_platform_support.html?lang=en) for more on platform restrictions.