# Listing Available networks in ios using IBM Worklight

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am new to work light. I want to create an application which shows me current available wifi network as a list and allow me to connect any of them and also it show the signal strength of the each network. I have studied the **WL.Device.Wifi** but it is not giving much help. Please provide your suggestions. I want to do this for iOS.

Comment: You can get them just with a private library, so your app can't be published on the app store. And I think you can only get the list, not connect to them

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i want to do this by using IBM Work light and my target platform is iOS.

Comment: here you have more info about the private library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317028/find-available-wi-fi-networks. You'll need to build a plugin

Comment: isn't it possible with WL.Device.wifi without using any plugin

Comment: no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, It will give the currently connected network but not the list of available networks. Apple not supporting that.

```
NSArray *ifs = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
    NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, ifs);
    id info = nil;
    for (NSString *ifnam in ifs)
    {
        info = (__bridge_transfer id)CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)ifnam);
        NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, ifnam, info);
        if (info && [info count])
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any solution using WL.Device.wifi API. and i want the list of available networks.

Answer (score 0):

There is limited support for what you're asking for, when using the WL.Device API in iOS.

You can see the following question&answer for more information about what is possible and any limitations: [How to list the available Wifi access point in worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25197173/how-to-list-the-available-wifi-access-point-in-worklight)

Comment: hello i was waiting for your reply to come. As you have worked a lot on this. So it means it is not possible in Work light. if not then is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Maybe it is possible using a Cordova plug-in that will execute native code. See the other answer you were given.

Comment: I have looked for iOS but it does not allow such type of functionality using public API. Cordova plugin is not helping out.

Comment: Then you cannot implement this.

Comment: For what purpose we use WL.Device.wifi i have studied it but it is not providing the clarity.

Comment: WL.Device.wifi is a collection of a different methods. You can read more about it in the Location Services training module: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/10_04_Location_services_in_worklight_applications.pdf You can read more in the IBM Worklight Knowledge Center.

Comment: can i have your email id or any source to contact you

Comment: location services are of different use and not full filling my requirement.